# Which is best display: block OR display: flex?

Tags: css

I am confused about using *display:block* or *display:flex*. Which is best to use?

Comment: It is very much depends on what outcome you wish to get, please extend what is your use case.

Comment: Their usage is different. Can't say which one is better

Answer (score 2):

There is no *better* or *best to use* here. These are just two valid values for the `display` property, and both come with a different effect to how elements are displayed (there are more possible values available).

> Every element on a web page is a rectangular box. The display property in CSS determines just how that rectangular box behaves.

– From [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

You won't just always use one of them, sometimes you will use the one and other times the other, this totally depends on what element/s you want to style and what output you would like.

Generally `block` displays the element as “one block/row”, while with `flex` you enable flexbox on the given element, which gives you a flexible set of layout options.

To understand the different concepts, you should check out the different values, see:

- [MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)
- [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)